# static resource versioning with Spring framework does not work

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to setup static resource versioning with Spring. I can get the versioned URL in my jsp. But when that request is placed, I get ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

in web.xml, I have this.

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I have configured mvc:resources

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/components/**" location="/components/" cache-period="31556926">
        <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true">
            <mvc:resolvers>
                <mvc:version-resolver>
                    <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
                </mvc:version-resolver>
            </mvc:resolvers>
        </mvc:resource-chain>
    </mvc:resources>
```

in my jsp, I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/components/abc/foo.js' />"></script>
```

I see that Spring returns foo-2ef843dad601376b6c3eaa6fec7df9b2.js.

But when this request is placed from the browser, I see following error in the browser console.
GET http://localhost:8080/a/components/abc/foo-2ef843dad601376b6c3eaa6fec7df9b2.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Update:

I created a simple Spring MVC app, and put versioning in it as described above. That worked fine. So this is related to having other elements in our application configuration. The major change is that we have Spring Security in it. Is anyone aware of any issues with using versioning and Spring Security together ? Thanks.

Comment: This is a Java, not javascript question. Corrected tag.

Comment: I am trying to do javascript versioning, that's why javascript. I should have put both in the tags.

Comment: I understand, but your issue is actually server side. Not on the client JS. You will get better help from the Java tag.

Comment: true. I see that you have changed the tag. thanks.